# Python Class Instance Arithmetic

Tags: python, class, math

I have a class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Where `a` is a float and `b` is a tuple containing a position in Cartesian coordinates.

Let's say `a = Foo(1.23, (1, 2))`.

What I want to do is make it so that if we do `a + 4.56` or `7.89 - a` or whatever, that it evaluates `a` to be a float object (`a.a`).

I know that I can just add the built in methods like `__add__` and `__sub__`, but is there a simpler way? As in one that provides the functionality in one method?

Comment: I don't think so. Otherwise, we can do `Foo()`+`Bar()` = `Egg()`. Python is magic. There are manual labor work. `+` is not overloaded so it will retain its standard functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a` is supposed to be a float, then I would recommend coercing it to a float.

```
float(a) + 4.56
```

Comment: For that to work, one needs to define `__float__`. But yet, explicit conversions are good.

Comment: Ah, after re-reading the question I misread it the first time.

Comment: @SeanLinehan: it would be useful to readers if you added the definition for the `float` method because without it, `float(a)` raises an exception.